# декодировка изображений в WinForms cli

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

в мне нужна помощь. В моем мессенджере требуется отправка не только сообщений, но и изображений разных форматов. Посоветуйте библиотеки или в принципе как декодировать изображения, а также как собрать из байтов изображение на другой стороне сети.

Answer (score 0):

Через консоль (system) преобразуй расширение командой ren в .txt затем читай файл и отправляй текст. На обратной стороне аналогично